# Protractor test suites and capabilities

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I want to be able to run specific suites using specific browser configuration, is this possible?. I try following code but unfortunate **when** suites are specified capability `specs` field is ignored and both test suites are executed in both browsers configuration.

```
{
    multiCapabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome',
            'chromeOptions': browserConfig.winOsSettings,
            specs: './e2e/test-suites/regression-test-suite/**/*.win.os.e2e-spec.ts'
        }, {
        browserName: 'chrome',
            'chromeOptions': browserConfig.ubuntuOsSettings,
            specs: './e2e/test-suites/regression-test-suite/**/*.ubuntu.e2e-spec.ts'
       }
    ],
    suites: {
        ubuntu_tests: '../e2e/test-suites/regression-test-suite/**/*.win.os.e2e-spec.ts',
        windows_tests: './e2e/test-suites/regression-test-suite/**/*.ubuntu.e2e-spec.ts',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the below code

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions':browserConfig.winOsSettings,
  specs: './e2e/test-suites/regression-test-suite/**/*.win.os.e2e-spec.ts'
}, {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': browserConfig.ubuntuOsSettings,
  specs: './e2e/test-suites/regression-test-suite/**/*.ubuntu.e2e-spec.ts'
}],
```